# I have two Lists of string how can i create a string from each List index with the other one?

Tags: c#

For example I have a List:

```
[0] daniel
[1] moses
```

Now the second List:

```
[0] hello world
[1] hi everyone
```

I want to build a new List of string that's will be:

```
[0] daniel hellow world
[1] moses hi everyone
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the LINQ [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method:

```
var result = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => string.Format("{0} {1}", f, s));
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use Linq / [**Enumerable.Zip**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) :

```
var list1 = new List<string>() {"daniel", "moses"};
var list2 = new List<string>() { "hello world", "hi everyone" };

var resultList = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => a + " " + b)
                      .ToList();
```